# How to change man page section of debian software?

Tags: debian, packaging, manpage

The package's manual page is in section 1 but I want it in section 8. What kind of changes do I have to do in git?

I tried renaming the package.1 file to package.8, but it did not help at least when I created the package by `dpkg-buildpackage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to denote the section in the contents of the manual page file.
If you create the file by `help2man` you have to use `--section` option, in this case `--section=8`.

`man 1 dh_installman` (for version 11.1.6ubuntu2) tells:

> If dh_installman seems to install a man page into the wrong section or
>   with the wrong extension, this is because the man page has the wrong
>   section listed in its .TH or .Dt line. Edit the man page and correct
>   the section, and dh_installman will follow suit. See man(7) for
>   details about the .TH section, and mdoc(7) for the .Dt section.